# Dead SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I have executed a routine that was doing a lots of data transformation and it seems to have rendered my SQL Server unusable, consuming lots of memory and CPU and doing something.

Currently, I need to just make the SQL Server stop doing whatever it's doing and I don't seem to be very successful even after many restarts. It makes the whole computer quite slow and I can't even login with the SSMS, neither can I run the profiler to see what's actually going on.

Is there some way to simply kill the processes inside the SQL Server ? I don't care about the data or logs, it's a developer machine and test database, so anything that makes him work would be great.

Comment: Do you mean just kill the process? There is a [taskkill command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) on XP and upwards.

Comment: You mean you've restarted the SQL Server and its still locked up? Thats weird.

Comment: Not really, I have killed the process already, even restarted the service a couple of times. After starting, it always does something and freezes the whole computer.

Comment: @codeulike : exactly, restarted everything I could (SQL Server, PC) couple of times.. still locked up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kill the sql server process you can open a task manager and simply kill the process, then you can move the database files to another location so that when the process starts again it doesn't go in recovery process.

After bringing up the sql server you can delete the database registeration in db and attach it later.

Comment: great, I moved the files away and now it works.. thanks a lot ;)